# Random graphics artifacts on Dell optiplex 780 with Radeon HD 3400

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, amd-radeon, dell-optiplex

I have a Dell Optiplex 780 with a ATI Radeon HD 3400 Series graphics card.

To it I have two Dell monitors connected, one P2210H and one P2211H.

After not using the computer for some 8 months I just recently reconnected monitors to it.

Since starting to use the machine again I've seen some weird graphical artifacts from time to time.

At first I thought it was some electrical interference in the room, so I switched from using VGA cables to DVI, but the problem persists.

Then I thought maybe the monitors where the problem, but today I realized I can screenshot the issue, leading to my believing it is something wrong with the graphics card and/or computer.

Here are two examples:

[image: one]

[image: two]

As you can see not all the screen gets garbled but only random portions.

If I scroll the text up and down it becomes normal again.

I've not seen a pattern that makes me able to predict when the issue might occur.

Should I just try getting a hold of a new graphics card, or might there be something else I can do to fix the issue?